# ForeColor of TreeNodes changes after selection

Tags: c#, forms, treeview

I've got a treeview with colored nodes depending on their state (saved ones are green, disabled ones are gray, rest is default). However, their ForeColor resets to default whenever a node gets selected

The nodes are being colored when the tree is being loaded with a simple 
`node.ForeColor = Color.Gray;`.

I've tried re-coloring the nodes with an AfterSelect event like this (simplified code a bit):

```cs
void wgtree_BeforeSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           previousNode = wgtree.SelectedNode;
        }
```

```cs
void wgtree_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    KeyValuePair<int, IBC> bc = (KeyValuePair<int, IBC>)tvBCTemplates.SelectedNode.Tag;

    string nodeID = previousNode.Name;
    if (Int32.TryParse(nodeID, out int wgid))
    {
        int bcid = GetBCID(wgid);
        if (bcid == 0)
        {
            previousNode.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else if (bcid == bc.Key)
        {
            previousNode.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            previousNode.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems the AfterSelect is still too "early" to color the previous node.

I guess I could run through the whole TreeView, but that doesn't seem very efficient as the user might create hundreds of nodes.

Comment: Well it really shouldn't change colors in the first place! How do you set the colors?

Comment: As I said, with a normal "node.ForeColor = Color.Gray;". I set break points at every color change and when it changes the color back, none of the break points gets hit. Good to know that the issue might be in my code, though, I'll see if I can find the cause.